# nodejs is either not installed or its executable not present in path

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, appium-android, nodejs-server

Whenever running an Appium test while starting appium server am facing an error saying `nodejs is either not installed or its executable not present in path`
I have installed node-js in my machine also installed appium through the command `npm install -g appium`

Comment: Did you get a fix for this issue? I have been experiencing the same. node and npm both installed correctly and added to the $PATH

Comment: Not yet, I guess we are both only on the planet with this issue.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same issue :(
Did it get resolved for any of you ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two arguments under appiumdriver like in this way AppiumDriver(url,cap);
URL:- appium point url.
Cap:- desiredCapability instance.

Comment: Can you please provide more details and possibly some sample code. It is difficult to how to act on this answer